# is 0 in the following Ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given $R=\mathbb R[x]$ and $I=(2x^3-3x^2+2x-3)+(2x^2-x-3)$

Is an Ideal of R? I don't understand what the quantity I is... Am I supposed to sum them together giving $2x^3-x^2+x-6$

Now here's the issue my friend and I are having:

Is 0 in this supposed Ideal I? Because who's to say that $x\in \mathbb R$.. Or am I interpreting it wrong... becasue if x is natural then the polynomial never equals 0, but if its rational then $3/2=x$ will do the job

I'm really getting confused by this, so any help is very much appreciated, thanks

Comment: $0$ is in every ideal. $x$ is an indeterminate, not a real number or a complex number or anything else.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear, I am to show whether or not I is an Ideal - we don't know that it is, so I'm trying to show it is or isn't by showing whether or not 0 is in it or not. Also... An Indeterminate? If it isn't a type of number... does that make it a variable?

Answer (score 2):

$(2x^3−3x^2+2x−3)+(2x^2−x−3)=\{a(2x^3−3x^2+2x−3)+b(2x^2−x−3)| a,b\in R\}$

By definition. Every ideal is an additive subgroup by definition so yes $0$ is contained in it. (Note $0\in R$ so set $a=b=0$).

Comment: How does the second and third property of an ideal hold in this case? How are they closed under addition?
And how is it true that for $r\in R$, and $a\in I$ that: $ar\in I$, and $ra\in I$? Surely something like $x^5$ multiplied by something of degree $x$ from the ideal will give $x^6$ which isn't in the ideal...?

Comment: Let $p(x)=2x^3-3x^2+2x-3,\;q(x)=2x^2-x-3$ then let $r_1,r_2 \in (p)+(q)$ so $r_1=aq+bp,\;r_2=cq+dp$ for some $a,b,c,d \in R$. then $r_1+r_2=(a+c)q+(b+d)p \in (p)+(q)$. Same for the other properties. Remember these 'constants' a,b,c,d  are also polynomials

Answer (score 1):

By definition $(P)$ is the set :

$$\{Q\times P|Q\in\mathbb{R}[x]\} $$

In particular $0=0\times P\in (P)$. If I take your set $I$ (which is indeed an ideal) then :

$$0=0\times (2x^3-3x^2+2x-3)+0\times (2x^2-x-3) $$

So $0\in I$ and there is no problem to show that it is a group as well as stable by multiplication by an element of $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

To go further I would say that $I$ can be put in a more interesting form :

$$I=(gcd(2x^3-3x^2+2x-3,2x^2-x-3)) $$

Hint: Use the Bezout's theorem for polynomials.